# Check whether an AST recursively contains a specific constructor

Tags: haskell

Take this simple data type (from the [Uniplate documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate-1.6/docs/Data-Generics-Uniplate-Operations.html)):

```
data Expr = Val Int
          | Neg Expr
          | Add Expr Expr
```

I want to check whether an expression tree contains a specific operation (in our case `Neg` and `Add`).

If we derive `Uniplate` for `Expr`, we'll be able to use [`universe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate-1.6/docs/Data-Generics-Uniplate-Operations.html#v:universe) in order to write these two simple functions:

```
hasNeg :: Expr -> Bool
hasNeg e = not $ null [() | Neg{} <- universe e]

hasAdd :: Expr -> Bool
hasAdd e = not $ null [() | Add{} <- universe e]
```

I'd like to extract the common code and write some "generic" function which will accept some information about the constructor, but I can't even think of a matching type signature, which is usually a bad sign. Does this function makes any sense, and what's the proper way of implementing it?

Thanks!

Comment: One option is `(Expr -> Bool) -> Expr -> Bool` but this requires a bunch of silly predicates like `isAdd` and `isNeg`.

Comment: @delnan Yes, it just shifts the problem around a bit.

Comment: In a similar vein to what delnan said, one possibility is to create a new enum for the constructor names: `data ExprTag = ValTag | NegTag | AddTag`

Comment: if you restrict yourself to ghc-7.8, you can use pattern synonyms.

Comment: @JohnL not sure I got your idea - I'll still have to write one synonym for each constructor, right?

Comment: Benesh: yes, but since pattern synonyms are just data they can be passed as parameters to the generalized function.  IMHO it's a bit nicer than "a bunch of silly predicates" (although it's basically the same as delnan's suggestion).

Comment: I don't think Uniplate does any metadata tracking, which would include constructor information, so the only way to discern constructors is what you get with just Haskell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Control.Lens.Plated`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.3.3/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html) has a similar API to `uniplate` (and the performance is about the same, too), but with  `lens` you can use prisms as first-class constructors:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.Extras

data Expr = Val Int
          | Neg Expr
          | Add Expr Expr deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Plated Expr where
    plate f (Val i)   = pure (Val i)
    plate f (Neg e)   = Neg <$> f e
    plate f (Add a b) = Add <$> f a <*> f b 

makePrisms ''Expr -- derives _Val, _Neg and _Add prisms

hasNeg :: Expr -> Bool 
hasNeg = any (is _Neg) . universe

hasPrism :: Prism' Expr a -> Expr -> Bool
hasPrism p = any (is p) . universe

hasAdd :: Expr -> Bool
hasAdd = hasPrism _Add 

hasNegNeg :: Expr -> Bool
hasNegNeg = hasPrism (_Neg . _Neg) -- matches (Neg (Neg x))
```

Comment: Didn't know about `Control.Lens.Plated`. Thanks for the answer!